# How could I correctly total the points?

Tags: javascript

I am javascript learner struggling to design  a small javascript game for my kids (5 to 10 years old) in which points are based on time elapsed. But, I cannot figure out a way to total the points. I have managed the code below but the result is not accurate. Probably the program is totalling all the items in array with each click. Can anybody help please? I am a newbie and there will be many mistakes or absurdities in here, I request you to be helpful politely while correcting me. Any help is appreciated..

```js
document.getElementById("box1").onclick = function() {
  clickT = Date.now();
  reactT = (clickT - createdT) / 1000; //gets the time difference for reaction.

  points = reactT * 1000;
  points = 2000 - points;

  pRecord.push(points); //add points to array.

  for (i = 0; i < pRecord.length; i++) {
    totalpoints += pRecord[i];
  }

  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = reactT;
  this.style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = totalpoints;
}
```

Comment: You need to set `totalpoints = 0;` before your loop, otherwise it will just keep adding to it.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH EVERY ONE FOR YOUR HELP AND ANSWER.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below since I noticed a problem with how you register the reaction points. Was it intentional to score negative points (instead of 0) when the reaction time is slower than 2 seconds?

Comment: Yes, I actually want to reduce children reaction time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `totalpoints` to zero before you sum the points:

```
document.getElementById("box1").onclick = function() {
    var clickT = Date.now();
    var reactT = (clickT - createdT) / 1000; //gets the time difference for reaction.

    var points = reactT * 1000;

    points = 2000 - points;

    pRecord.push(points); //add points to array.

    var totalpoints = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < pRecord.length; i++){
       totalpoints += pRecord[i];
    }


    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = reactT;
    this.style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = totalpoints;
}
```

And also I don't know if you defined your variables in the outer scope, but I guess you did not, so I added `var` before every variable creation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of your code that also properly registers the reaction times, capping the maximum allowed reaction time to a configured value.

In your original implementation you could get bad readings if the reaction time was greater than 2 seconds.

Also, in your original code, you don`t need to divide by 1000 and then multiply back, since you end up with milliseconds anyway.

This is it:

```js
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  clickT = Date.now();

  // Gets the time difference in milliseconds for reaction.
  reactT = clickT - createdT; 

  // Maximum allowed reaction time after which we give no more points.
  var maxPoints = 2000;

  // We cap the registered reaction time to the maximum allowed.
  points = Math.max(reactT, maxPoints);
  // We score the reaction time based
  points = maxPoints - points;

  // Add points to array.
  pRecord.push(points); 

  // Compute the total points.
  var totalpoints = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < pRecord.length; i++){
    totalpoints += pRecord[i];
  }

  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = reactT;
  this.style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = totalpoints;
}
```

You can notice that I have defined the `totalpoints` variable (and initialized it with 0), as otherwise, at each click, all your scores were re-added, not just the last one.

I have made the assumption that `totalpoints` was not already defined before the code you have pasted. Should this assumption be wrong and you have already initialized `totalpoints` before, in your code, then you need to replace the following piece from my code:

```
// Compute the total points.
var totalpoints = 0;
for (i = 0; i < pRecord.length; i++){
  totalpoints += pRecord[i];
}
```

...with:

```
// Add the new points to the total.
totalpoints += points;
```

Comment: Yes, I actually want to reduce children reaction time. But, your code gave me a new idea. Thanks for that.